# Netty pipeline warning

Tags: netty

Netty 4 issues a warning "Discarded 1 inbound message(s) that reached at the end of the pipeline. Please check your pipeline configuration". What does it mean? how should it be handled?
(previously [reproduced here](https://github.com/cloudaloe/pipe) until solved per the accepted answer, but I'd rather have the general explanation about what does it mean and how the pipeline works)

Trying to max out netty feedback, the client-side pipeline is set as follows:

```
pipeline.addLast("logger", new LoggingHandler(LogLevel.TRACE))
pipeline.addLast("HttpRequestEncoder", new HttpClientCodec)
pipeline.addLast("handler", new myHandler)
```

All I'm getting logged on the client-side by Netty while two http messages are sent by it and successfully received and acknowledged by the server side is:

```
12 [main] DEBUG io.netty.util.internal.InternalLoggerFactory  - Using Log4J as the default logging framework
164 [nioEventLoopGroup-1-2] DEBUG io.netty.channel.nio.SelectorUtil  - Using select timeout of 500
164 [nioEventLoopGroup-1-2] DEBUG io.netty.channel.nio.SelectorUtil  - Epoll-bug workaround enabled = false
229 [nioEventLoopGroup-1-2] WARN io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline  - Discarded 1 inbound message(s) that reached at the end of the pipeline. Please check your pipeline configuration.
230 [nioEventLoopGroup-1-2] WARN io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline  - Discarded 1 inbound message(s) that reached at the end of the pipeline. Please check your pipeline configuration.
```

Whereas logging is set up minimally as so:

```
BasicConfigurator.configure       
InternalLoggerFactory.setDefaultFactory(new Log4JLoggerFactory)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Netty 4, HTTP decoders, used in servers or clients, always generates multiple message objects per a single HTTP message:

```
1       * HttpRequest / HttpResponse
0 - n   * HttpContent
1       * LastHttpContent
```

In other words:

- a server receive 1 HttpRequest, 0-n HttpContent(s) and 1 HttpLastContent
- a client receive 1 HttpResponse, 0-n HttpContent(s) and 1 HttpLastContent.

So if your handler only consume HttpRequest/HttpResponse the other messages will reach the end of the pipeline. You need to consume them, this is where your pipeline is "misconfigured".

OTOH you can add a HttpObjectAggregator to your pipeline so that FullHttpRequest/FullHttpResponse messages are generated instead:

```
pipeline.addLast( "http-aggregator", new HttpObjectAggregator( MAX_SIZE ) );
```

But it means that the whole request or response, including the body entity, is loaded before your handler is invoked. Maybe you don't want that, YMMV.

Comment: So how come the discarded message warning is issued on the client side? Doesn't your answer imply that the problem is with the decoder, which is on the server side? what am I missing? Thanks!

Comment: From what I understand, this is true for servers AND clients. Both use the HttpCodec and work in the same way. I edited my answer to make that clear.

Comment: Not sure how this applies to the client in the edited answer (are you saying the client receives a LastHttpContent object from the server which makes it issue the warning?). I expected the client receiving http responses, not http requests.

Comment: Yeah, in one place in my answer I did not put HttpResponse next to HttpRequest. I edited it once again to fix that and added some content to make explicit that server or client doesn't matter (just swap *Request for *Response).

Comment: Thanks for the info. What should be MAX_SIZE?

Answer (score 5):

Netty 4 automatically add one last handler on your created pipeline, if event reaches this last handler it will through the message. Your last inbound handler should not fire the context event.

Remove this: 
ctx.fireChannelRead(msg);

Answer (score 2):

@eskatos is right, the pipeline's handler processing based on type matching, for example, `SimpleChannelInboundHandler<HttpContent>` will just process HttpContent, if you had not processed HttpReponse yet(add `SimpleChannelInboundHandler<HttpReponse>` into you pipeline), Netty will warning: Content-Length: `<length>` that reached at the tail of the pipeline. Please check your pipeline configuration.

So, the solution is to add corresponding `ChannelInboundHandler/ChannelOutboundHandler` into your pipeline.

But you need to know what's typed Handler missing first:
find the DefaultChannelPipeline's channelRead method and debug into it to get msg.content().toString() that includes what the message missing.

One more thing, @`Norman Maurer` mentioned to enable debug logging is not working, because channelRead method does not log what's inside of the msg's content.

The channelRead method of DefaultChannelPipeline below here (Netty 4.1):

```
    @Override
    public void channelRead(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object msg) throws Exception {
        try {
            logger.debug(
                    "Discarded inbound message {} that reached at the tail of the pipeline. " +
                            "Please check your pipeline configuration.", msg);
        } finally {
            ReferenceCountUtil.release(msg);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

This means that a message reached the end of the pipeline and no "inbound handler" was able to handle it. This most of the times shows a "configuration" error in the ChannelPipeline.

Comment: Thanks, this is more or less what I thought it means, but am looking for suggestions on how to explore a solution. In my case (as seen inside the repo running main.scala) the pipeline is setup for http on both the sender and receiver sides, and the messages sent are http. Could you suggest how can it be explored? "configuration error" is a very generic notion. Also can that message that supposedly went unhandled be extracted somehow?

Comment: enable debug logging in netty and it should log what kind of message is dropped

Comment: Added logging outputs in the question body. Didn't get too much logging info there. Should I enable logging any differently?

Comment: Netty log the discarded inbound message at DEBUG level. Using 4.0.0.Beta3 I get this log: """DEBUG io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline - Discarded inbound message io.netty.handler.codec.http.LastHttpContent$1@b68d372 that reached at the end of the pipeline. Please check your pipeline configuration."""